# Error when using RecyclerView (No adapter attached; skipping layout)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am facing the error "RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout" and I searched the related solutions, but the error still exists.

I've tried to initialize views and data in onCreate() method, but still got the same error. And I've refered to [RecyclerViewFragment.java from Android Developer site](https://developer.android.com/samples/RecyclerView/src/com.example.android.recyclerview/RecyclerViewFragment.html) code, and some libraries initialize views in onCreateView() method.

The activity's layout contains tablayout and viewpager for switching fragments.
And FragmentList is one of those fragments.

Here are my partial codes:

```
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {
View view;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
AppCompatActivity activity;
RecyclerView list_container;
Adapter recyclerviewAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Activity a = getActivity();
    if (a instanceof AppCompatActivity)
        activity = (AppCompatActivity) a;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    initViews();
    return view;
}

private void initViews() {
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefreshlayout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getColor(R.color.colorAccentLight), getColor(R.color.colorAccent), getColor(R.color.colorAccentDark));
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

    list_container = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_container);
    list_container.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    list_container.setLayoutManager(manager);
    list_container.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    List<Test> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Test(new String("0"), 0));
    list.add(new Test(new String("1"), 1));
    list.add(new Test(new String("2"), 3));
    recyclerviewAdapter = new Adapter(list);

    list_container.setAdapter(recyclerviewAdapter);

}

private int getColor(int res) {
    return ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), res);
}

class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<holder> {
    List<Test> list;

    public Adapter(List<Test> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void add(Test test) {
        list.add(test);
    }
    @Override
    public holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d("", "onCreateViewHolder: " + viewType);
        View vvv = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.testlayout, parent, false);
        return new holder(vvv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(holder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("", "onBindViewHolder: " + position);
        holder.title.setText(list.get(position).str);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("", "getItemCount: " + list.size());
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Log.d("", "getItemViewType: " + position);
        return list.get(position).id;
    }
}

static class holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View view;
    TextView title;

    public holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    }
}

class Test {
    String str;
    int id;

    public Test(String str, int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.str = str;
    }
}
}
```

fragment_list.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/fragment_list_appbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefreshlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

testlayout.xml is for the viewholder's view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please tell me where the problem is. Thanks.

**UPDATED**

I updated the partial code and the others remain the same. But the view dose not show anything.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Activity a = getActivity();
    if (a instanceof AppCompatActivity)
        activity = (AppCompatActivity) a;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefreshlayout);
    list_container = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_container);
    recyclerviewAdapter = new Adapter();
    list_container.setAdapter(recyclerviewAdapter);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    initViews();
}

private void initViews() {
    //swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefreshlayout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getColor(R.color.colorAccentLight), getColor(R.color.colorAccent), getColor(R.color.colorAccentDark));
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

    //list_container = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_container);
    list_container.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    list_container.setLayoutManager(manager);
    list_container.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    List<Test> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Test(new String("0"), 0));
    list.add(new Test(new String("1"), 1));
    list.add(new Test(new String("2"), 3));
    //recyclerviewAdapter = new Adapter();
    recyclerviewAdapter.add(list);
    recyclerviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //list_container.setAdapter(recyclerviewAdapter);
}

private int getColor(int res) {
    return ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), res);
}

class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<holder> {
    List<Test> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public Adapter() {
    }

    public void add(Test test) {
        list.add(test);
    }

    public void add(List<Test> test) {
        list.addAll(test);
    }

    @Override
    public holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (list == null || list.size() == 0) return null;
        Log.e("", "onCreateViewHolder: " + viewType);
        View vvv = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.testlayout, parent, false);
        holder hh = new holder(vvv);
        return hh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(holder holder, int position) {
        if (holder == null) return;
        Log.e("", "onBindViewHolder: " + position);
        holder.title.setText(list.get(position).str);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.e("", "getItemCount: " + list.size());
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Log.e("", "getItemViewType: " + position);
        return list.get(position).id;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean call" notifyDataSetChanged" after "setAdapter"? I tried and got the same error.

Comment: I found the problem LOL.  The textview's textcolor and the layout's background color are the same.

Answer (score 0):

First pass the empty list to the adapter,Second after getting data notify the adapter (eg, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged). Another thing in your oncreateView method do findViewById only. Other initialization and passing data to adapter do it in onActivityCreated().
Remove the adapter code from onCreateView.
Now let's look into the code.

```
    //Global Declaration;
    List<Text> list=new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

//Inside onActivityCreated
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

            mAdapter = new Adapter(list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
//Do your list.add here then notify adapter
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```